# RESTful route for many-to-many with double records in a Backbone application

Tags: rest, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I have a database schema with `Reservations` and `Products`.

A `reservation` can have multiple `products` and a `product` can have multiple `reservations`.
A reservation can also have a product **multiple times**. 
I have a many-to-many relation set-up for this, which works well.

Now I'm porting this schema over to my Backbone application where I use a BackboneRelational setup having a `Reservation` model, `ReservationProduct` model and a `ReservationProducts` collection. In My `Reservation` model i defined a hasMany link to `ReservationProducts`.

All works fine but I'm wondering which RESTful routes I should use for a `PUT` or `DELETE` call on a `Product`.

I'm wondering how I should deal with the the fact that a reservation can have a product multiple times.

Would a `DELETE` call for example be pointed at

`/reservation/:reservation_id/product/:reservation_product_id`
(This is the one backbone generates for me)

or this one:

`/reservation_product/:id`

?

And if so, which RESTful route is correct:

`/reservation/:reservation_id/product/:reservation_product_id`

`/reservation/:reservation_id/product/:product_id`